# Фон на CSS

Tags: css

У меня есть: background-color: #58e900
Как место кода цвета сделать фон картинко kart1.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-image: url("myfile.png");
```

Но

```
background-color: #fff;
```

тогда как

```
background: #fff url("myfile.png") center center no-repeat;
```

подробнее на [htmlbook:css/background](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background)

Answer (score 2):

```
background-image: URL(kart1.gif);
background-repeat: repeat; /*no-repeat/repeat-x/repeat-y*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url( {путь к картинке}/kart1.gif ) no-repeat 0 0;
```